# Unknown source file : com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzpq;

Tags: java, android, gradle, react-native

Suddenly we get build-errors for the android part of our React-Native app, which builds perfectly on iOS and which is in the stores since many months (AppStore and PlayStore). Some days ago i could perfectly build the android version, but now this error occurs:

```
:app:generateReleaseSources
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources
:app:lintVitalRelease
:app:preDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexRelease
Unknown source file : UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Unknown source file : com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzpq;
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
Unknown source file :   at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:app:dexRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexRelease'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

After google-ing a while i've found out that this can be occured by third party libraries. so i deactivated all libs that was added in the last two weeks. The error remains.

Is there any possibility to debug this error to find out the root cause?

---

### Update:

This is the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"]
 * ]
 */

 buildscript {
    repositories {
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
      // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
      // quickly to Android tooling updates
      classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
 }

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zizzle.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 39
        versionName "1.26.88"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
      signingConfigs {
              release {
                  storeFile file(ZIZZLE_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                  storePassword ZIZZLE_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                  keyAlias ZIZZLE_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                  keyPassword ZIZZLE_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
              }
      }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
  // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-uuid-generator')
    compile project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    compile project(':react-native-billing')
    compile project(':react-native-code-push')
    compile project(':react-native-extra-dimensions-android')
    compile project(':react-native-sound')
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')
    compile project(':react-native-code-push')
    compile project(':react-native-fabric')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
         transitive = true;
       }

    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

      compile project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')
    compile project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.compile
  into 'libs'
}
```

### Update 2

After suggestions of @michele i've updated build.gradle, the error is another one now:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllReleaseClassesForMultiDex'.
>
>   > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzpy.class

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"]
 * ]
 */

 buildscript {
    repositories {
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
      // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
      // quickly to Android tooling updates
      classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
 }

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zizzle.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 39
        versionName "1.26.88"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
      signingConfigs {
              release {
                  storeFile file(ZIZZLE_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                  storePassword ZIZZLE_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                  keyAlias ZIZZLE_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                  keyPassword ZIZZLE_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
              }
      }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
  // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-billing')
    compile project(':react-native-code-push')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-extra-dimensions-android')
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')
    compile project(':react-native-fabric')
    compile project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')
    compile project(':react-native-sound')
    compile project(':react-native-uuid-generator')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
         transitive = true;
       }

    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.compile
  into 'libs'
}
```

Comment: post your `build.gradle` please

Comment: @MicheleLacorte done :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by a specific library called "react-native-device-info".

After including this library the error in my question happens, and after exluding this library, everything works fine again.

I've opened an issue on github:
https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/issues/102

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"]
 * ]
 */

 buildscript {
    repositories {
      maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
      // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
      // quickly to Android tooling updates
      classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
 }

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zizzle.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 39
        versionName "1.26.88"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
      signingConfigs {
              release {
                  storeFile file(ZIZZLE_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                  storePassword ZIZZLE_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                  keyAlias ZIZZLE_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                  keyPassword ZIZZLE_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
              }
      }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
  // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-billing')
    compile project(':react-native-code-push')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-extra-dimensions-android')
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    compile project(':react-native-i18n')
    compile project(':react-native-fabric')
    compile project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')
    compile project(':react-native-sound')
    compile project(':react-native-uuid-generator')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
         transitive = true;
       }

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.compile
  into 'libs'
}
```

Comment: this results an another error:

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllReleaseClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzpy.class

Comment: `compile project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')` delete this line! There is twice

Comment: If you not resolve, finally remove this other line:
`compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])` @itinance

Comment: thx! there was another doubled line (code-push), the error remained. will try now with removing of "compile fileTree..."

Comment: the error remains. i've updated my question with latest build.gradle-file

Comment: thx a lot for your patience. i've applied the complete file. it still stucks with * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllReleaseClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzpy.class

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' add this in build.gradle and extend ur application class as MutlidexApplication , add MultiDex.install(this); in attachBaseContext method if it's  not added .

Comment: this is a react-native-application and multidex wasn't really a topic until now. what happend? i can't extend the application from MultiDexApplication because the RN-inheritance would be gone then

Comment: thank you both very much. i've finally found the root cause. it's a rn-library, where i've opened an issue https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/issues/102